# How to make rule based symbology map

Tags: qgis

I am trying to make a map based off of 3 distinct data columns to map out which is the biggest in each ward for my vector layer but I cannot seem to find a way to do it.

My goal here is to make so that the biggest value for each ward show in colour. For instance in this case, say I have Ward A, with the 3 value columns of Bob (Green), Eric (Blue), and John (Red), and their values for this ward is 300, 200 and 150 respectively. I basically want the map to show the ward as green as Bob in this case is the biggest.

Answer (score 2):

One simple way to do it is shown in the screenshot below. With this set of rules, if there are any of the 2 columns equal in value, the colour for ELSE is displayed.  So it would need to be edited to reflect what columns take prority e.g. bob>= eric and bob >= john etc...

[image]

Here is a screenshot of how to add 1st rule:
[image]

Here is a screenshot of how to add 2nd rule:
[image]

Adding the ELSE rule:
[image]

Comment: OK perfect, I had a feeling it had something to with the rule based option, thank you. How would I go about attaching the data columns to said labels? Do I need to set the labels on as the same name as the delimited text layer columns? 

When I try doing as default as what you have shown all get put under ELSE and I can't seem to go from there on how to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: original post edited